# Using custom method security annotation in spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, annotations

I want to tag methods in a class with a custom annotation that will control authorization decisions using spring security. For example:

```
@Role("ADMIN")
public void accessControlledMethod(){}
```

I understand that this means I somehow need to register my custom annotation "Role" so that it can result in `ConfigAttributes` being present when an authorization decision is made by the `AccessDecisionManager`. However, I do not understand how to register my custom annotation with spring security so that it will be recognized.

I see one potential solution in the framework code. There is a class called SecuredAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource whose documentation says "inject AnnotationMetadataExtractor for custom annotations". If that is the preferred method, I'm not sure how to configure the SecuredAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource or how to inject the AnnotationMetadataExtractor into it.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using custom anotations instead that the ones provided by Spring Security?

Comment: @XtremeBiker My team has an existing authorization framework in place that uses a different naming convention specific to our application. I want to use those role names in our method security annotations. The method documentation makes it clear this is somehow supported, but I can't find any information on how it works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can extend `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration` in your configuration :

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
@Configuration
public class MyMethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    protected MethodSecurityMetadataSource customMethodSecurityMetadataSource() {
        return SecuredAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource(...);
    }    
}
```

In xml, you can do :

```
<global-method-security metadata-source-ref="customMethodSecurityMetadataSource">
...
</global-method-security>
<bean id="customMethodSecurityMetadataSource"  class="org.springframework.security.access.annotation.SecuredAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource">
...
</bean>
```

customMethodSecurityMetadataSource can be any instanceof MethodSecurityMetadataSource

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm currently using XML configuration, is there an equivalent XML configuration?

Comment: Thanks, I had accidentally listed the wrong XSD and it was saying metadata-source-ref isn't supported. Whoops.

Comment: Also, I should note that this global-method-security configuration should be in the servlet.xml configuration not in the security.xml configuration.

Answer (score 3):

This is not working in Spring 5 becuase default bean overriding is disabled by default. It works only with `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding` property set to `true`.

If anyone have some idea how to add custom `MethodSecurityMetadataSource` to `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration` without bean override enabling, it will be helpful for newer Spring version

Comment: Just stumbled across this problem, try my answer.

Answer (score -1):

In Spring Boot you can add custom `MethodSecurityMetadataSource`s and `AccessDecisionVoter`s by overriding the corresponding methods in `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration` and adding/modifying the values form the superclass.

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter(SecurityConfiguration.class)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
    @Override
    public MethodSecurityMetadataSource methodSecurityMetadataSource() {
        var source = (DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource) super.methodSecurityMetadataSource();
        source.getMethodSecurityMetadataSources().add(new FooSecurityMetadataSource());
        return source;
    }

    @Override
    protected AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
        var manager = (AffirmativeBased) super.accessDecisionManager();
        manager.getDecisionVoters().add(new FooVoter());
        return manager;
    }
}
```

Comment: Implementing the `customMethodSecurityMetadataSource()` method does the exact same thing, except that it doesn't rely on the current implementation. So this is not a very good answer if you ask me.

Comment: Yea, you are probably right. Not sure why I didn't see this back then.